# How do I access the __init__.py file on linux?

Tags: tor

I need to get to this file to fix an issue with running tor but I cant figure out how to get to it.

Comment: Hi and welcome - can you add some more context here? How have you reached the conclusion that you need to access this file? Are you getting an error message somewhere? What have you tried to do and what exactly is happening? I'm not going to close this question as it's possible that some expert might understand your problem from the limited explanation you've posted, but more information would most likely help us to help you and future readers as well. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: A file of that name must exist in any directory which constitutes a python module. In order to find the one that you want, you need to know which module it relates to. As @Zanna has said, you should add context to your post, including any error message(s).

Comment: I agree with @Zanna that you might need to go back and redefine/fully understand the problem rather than blindly trying to edit a file without understanding why. Anyway, to find all files called `__init__.py`, deep to the current directory the following command might help: `find . -name '__init__.py'`